# Is there a way in oracle sql to get a count with cross join?

Tags: sql, count, cross-join

I need to take a list of majors and a list of letter grades and I need to get the number of courses completed within the major associated with the letter grade. So if i have:

```
Major
Mechanical Engineer
Electrical Engineer
Civil Engineer
Chemical Engineer 
...

Grade
A
B
C
...

Student
100 - Alice - Mechanical Engineer
101 - Tom - Mechanical Engineer
102 - Rex - Mechanical Engineer
103 - Bob - Mechanical Engineer
104 - John - Civil Engineer 
105 - Alex - Electrical Engineer

Course
001 - Solid Mechanics - 100 - A
002 - Thermodynamics - 100 - A
003 - Heat Transfer - 100 - A 
004 - Heat Transfer - 101 - A
005 - Gadgetry - 100 - A
006 - Gadgetry - 101 - A
007 - Gadgetry - 102 - A
008 - Dynamics - 102 - A
009 - Gadgetry - 101 - C
010 - Heat Transfer - 102 - C
011 - Fluid Mechanics - 100 - B 
012 - Materials - 102 -B 
013 - Intro to EE - 105 - B
014 - Embedded Systems - 105 - B
015 - Analog Circuits - 105 - B
...
```

I need an output of:

```
Mechanical Engineer - A - 8
Mechanical Engineer - B - 2
Mechanical Engineer - C - 2
Electrical Engineer - A - 0
Electrical Engineer - B - 3
...
```

There is another table with students that says which major each student is in, and a course table with which student took what course (some students can take no courses) and what grade they received from that course.

So far I have:

```
SELECT major_name, grade, COUNT(grade_code) OVER (PARTITION BY major_name)
FROM Major CROSS JOIN ((grade LEFT JOIN course USING (grade_code)) RIGHT JOIN student USING (st_id))
ORDER BY major_name, grade;
```

But the count is not working (getting the same incorrect count for each major), essentially the total count of the letter grade from the course table.

```
Mechanical Engineer - A - 10
Mechanical Engineer - B - 10
Mechanical Engineer - C - 10
Electrical Engineer - A - 10
...
```

Comment: Have sample table data and expected result that match. (How else could we verify the count?)

Comment: I made up some sample data on the fly, so hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for `CROSS JOIN` or an aggregate `COUNT...OVER()` window function. Simply join the main tables ( *student* and *course*) and then the lookup tables (*major* and *grade*). Then, aggregate for count. Because *major* links to *student* which is not in `FROM` clause, replace `USING` for the traditional `ON` by corresponding aliases:

```
SELECT m.major_name, 
       g.grade, 
       count(*) as major_grade_count
FROM course c
LEFT JOIN student s USING (st_id)
LEFT JOIN grade g USING (grade_code)
LEFT JOIN major m ON g.major_code = m.major_code      -- ADJUST FIELD HERE
GROUP BY  m.major_name, 
          g.grade;
```